# Apex repeat component not displaying column header when used with a map

Tags: apex, visualforce, map, repeat

I have a wrapper class with map inside, which i need to display in a visualforce page in a page block table with column headers. Also i wanted to build an export feature on this table so i should be rendering data in the table in Page Block Table. But i'm facing a challenge with column header in page block table , which is currently not working with map ( i used repeat component). Can anyone suggest me an alternative or a fix for this issue.

I'm attaching the wrapper class and the page block table for a reference.

Wrapper Class:

```
   public class historyWrapper
    {
        public History__c hs{get;set;}
        public Map<String,String> keyValueMap{get;set;}

        historyWrapper(History__c h)
        {
            hs = h;
            keyValueMap = new map<String,String>();

            for(String s: h.Stage_String__c.Split(';'))
            {
                keyValueMap.put(s.split(':')[0],s.split(':')[1]);        
            }
        }

}
```

Visual force Page:

```
<apex:pageBlockTable var="hs" value="{!historyWrp}">

            <apex:repeat var="key" value="{!hs.keyValueMap}">

            <apex:column >
                <apex:facet name="header">{!key}</apex:facet>
                {!hs.keyValueMap[key]}
            </apex:column>                

            </apex:repeat>        

</apex:pageBlockTable>
```

The variable historyWrp is a list of wrapper  class historyWrapper. I hope it will avoid all confusion.

What i'm trying here is every wrapper record will have list of key value pairs(like new:10;Working:20; etc..) that i would need to display as column in visualforce page with value. The final page will be like New|Working as column header and 10|20 as values beneath it.

Comment: In the apex:column, you defined {!hs.keyValueMap}  as variable KEY.  And in the column value you put {!hs.keyValueMap[KEY]}.  So that's Map[Map].  Is that right?  Shouldn't it be just KEY?

Comment: The way you accessing variables is not clear. Can you set `value` property of `apex:repeat` into `value="{!keyValueMap}"` and check

Answer (score 1):

works for me using account object:

```
public class AccountController {
public AccountWrapper accWrap {get;set;}

public AccountController(ApexPages.StandardController stdController) 
{
    Account a = (Account)stdController.getRecord();

    a.Name = 'new:10;Working:20;';

    accWrap  = new accountWrapper(a);
}

public class AccountWrapper
{
    public Account acc{get;set;}
    public Map<String,String> keyValueMap{get;set;}

    accountWrapper(Account a)
    {
        acc = a;
        keyValueMap = new map<String,String>();

        for(String s: a.Name.Split(';'))
        {
            keyValueMap.put(s.split(':')[0],s.split(':')[1]);        
        }
    }
}
}
```

VISUALFORCE PAGE

```
<apex:page standardController="Account" extensions="AccountController" >
<apex:pageblock >
<apex:pageBlockTable var="accWrap" value="{!accWrap}">

        <apex:repeat var="key" value="{!accWrap.keyValueMap}">

        <apex:column >
            <apex:facet name="header">{!key}</apex:facet>
            {!accWrap.keyValueMap[key]}
        </apex:column>                

        </apex:repeat>        

</apex:pageBlockTable>
```

Comment: But when you use with a list of wrapper class to iterate over the page block table the headers will disappear for the repeat component.

E.g Instead of public AccountWrapper accWrap, try using public List<AccountWrapper> accWrap. You will notice that header will be missing for the repeat component.

Comment: <apex:facet> component is supported under only specific parent components like pageBlockTable.  It is not supported under a repeat tag..

Comment: https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F0000000An5FIAS